# Best Practice to access a Model from a Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

So basically I've got a question about how to do this in the best way possible. And I'm not even sure I'm doing it right in the first place.

I got a settings page where the user can update some settings. When the form is submitted, the method below is taking care of the request as you can see.

I do have a `Profile` model as well as an `User` model, and their relations are also setup right.

But as you can see, everything is done in the controller in this method. I dont use the `Profile` model at all. But shouldn't i?

What method could I make and use in the `Profile` model so I could do less in the controller?

Sorry if this is an unappropriate question.

Thanks in advance.

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 *
 * Process general settings
 */
public function postEditGeneralSettings() {

    // Validate
    $val = Validator::make([
        'show_age'    => Input::get('show_age'),
        'show_gender' => Input::get('show_gender')
    ], [
        'show_age'    => 'sometimes|boolean',
        'show_gender' => 'sometimes|boolean'
    ]);

    if ($val -> fails()) {
        return $this -> backWithErrors($val);
    }

    // Update
    Auth::user() -> profile() -> update([
        'show_age'    => Input::get('show_age'),
        'show_gender' => Input::get('show_gender')
    ]);

    return $this -> backWithSuccess('Innstillingene ble lagret!');

}
```

Comment: Looks pretty good. I'd just suggest you use Form Request instead of `Validator::make` because then you have a better SOC.

Comment: Ah, I see. Should there be a new request class for each new post process? Like, editGeneralSettings, editSecuritySettings, editText, editStatus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Repository class to push out the responsability of storing the data from the controller:

```
class UserRepository
{
    //rules for validation, as an alternative you can put them in your User Model
    public static $rules =  [
        'title' => 'required|unique|max:255',
        'body' => 'required',
    ];

    public function updateUserProfile($user, $data)
    {
        $user->profile()->update([
        'show_age'    => $data('show_age'),
        'show_gender' => $data('show_gender')
    ]);        
}
```

And then use the repository from the controller:

```
public function postEditGeneralSettings(UserRepository $repo) 
{    
    //an alternative to your validation, using the ValidatesRequests trait of the controller
    //this will give the same results of your validation, but is more concise
    $this->validate( CUserRepository::$rules, Input::all() );

    // Update using the repository
    $repo->update( Auth::user(), Input::all() );

    return $this->backWithSuccess('Innstillingene ble lagret!');   
}
```

Comment: I'll try to implement this. I was just wondering, where would I put this class in the folder structure (is there a CLI command I could use to generate the class)? And would I need a lot of repository classes? Or just one for each thing (UserRepo, ProfileRepo, GalleryRepo, MessagesRepo)?

Comment: I tend to avoid relying on Facades since they're practically a shortcut. With my suggestion, this method would receive a FormRequest class instead of a UserRepository and the validation rules would be in the FormRequest class. You could also inject the Repository in the construct of the controller. For Repository pattern, I suggest github.com/andersao/l5-repository which is practically a complete solution.

Comment: @Kaizokupuffball : which repositories to use and where to put them is up to you: it depends on your needs. Usually i use one repository per model.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu : i tend to use `FormRequest` for more complex validation (i.e forms with many fields), and keep the validation in the controller for simpler validation, but this is only a matter of preferences. If you don't like Facades, just auto-inject the `Request` object in the method and use `$request->all()` instead of `Input::all()` :)

Answer (score 1):

As Marco said, nothing wrong here.

You can also use the default `validate` method call for the validation instead of needing to create a specific form request. Generally I reach for specific form requests classes if the validation becomes complex, otherwise the inline is perfect. What is nice with the `validate` function it throws a validation exception that is caught and redirects back with the errors set etc.

Also nothing wrong with using Eloquent for what it is, embracing the active record pattern. If you wanted to be a little more explicit you could wrap the update as follows.

```php
public function postEditGeneralSettings(Request $request) 
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'show_age'    => 'sometimes|boolean',
        'show_gender' => 'sometimes|boolean',
    ]);

    auth()->user()->updateProfile([
        'show_age'    => $request->input('show_age'),
        'show_gender' => $request->input('show_gender'),
    ]);

    return $this->backWithSuccess('Innstillingene ble lagret!');
}

class User extends Model
{
    ...
    public function updateProfile($settings)
    {
        $this->profile()->update($settings);
    }
}
```